# Powershell - Using a list in a switch statement

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Firstly, forgive me, as I'm new to PowerShell.

I'm trying to find a way to give a little brevity to the following switch statement:

```
Switch ($a)

{
   {$_ -eq "option1" -or $_ -eq "option2"}{Do the same thing...}
}
```

Is there a way to change the `{$_ -eq "option1" -or $_ -eq "option2"}` clause to be more of a "if $a in this list" (but obviously without just using an `if`, otherwise I might as well just replace the switch).

There will eventually be a number of clauses in this switch statement, some of which may have 4 or 5 options, so brevity would help a lot, or it'll be a big statement.

Comment: well, "if $a in this list" is as close as it can be, there is `-in` in PowerShell :) `{ $_ -in 'option1', 'option2' }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`-in` or `-contains` containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) to simplify the conditions:

```bash
switch ($a) {
   { $_ -in "option1", "option2" } { # OR: { "option1", "option2" -contains $_ }
       # Do the same thing...
   }
}
```

If you have a very big list to compare and many items to process with your `switch`, you can consider using the `.Contains` method from `HashSet<T>` for fast lookups:

```
$hash = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [string[]] ('option1', 'option2'), [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)

switch('option1', 'option2', 'option3') {
    { $hash.Contains($_) } {
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good enough for my requirements. Regex doesn't really work with the potential list of items I need to validate against (unfortunately)

Comment: if its a very big list and you have many items to process you can consider changing the `-in` operator for a `HashSet<T>` and using its `.Contains` method that would be much faster. @Tufty

Comment: @Tufty added the `HashSet<T>` example to my answer, might be useful if you need better performance

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would go for a Regex switch

```
$a = 'option1'
switch -Regex ($a) {
    # with regex, the | symbol means OR
    'option1|option2' { <# Do the same thing... #> }
    default           { <# Do something else if the above does not apply #> }
}
```

Using regex gives you a more options on the comparisons. For instance:

- if the string in `$a` needs to be checked case-sensitively, you can add parameter `-CaseSensitive` to the switch cmd.
- if the string in `$a` needs to be checked as 'whole word' you can do `'^(option1|option2)$'`. (the `^` and `$` are line anchors, from start-of-string to end-of-string)
- if the value in `$a` needs to **contain** one of the words as whole word do `'\b(option1|option2)\b'` (the `\b` means a word boundary)

---

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) commented, when using regex, you need to make sure the words you are testing have all characters that have special meaning in regex (see table below) are **escaped with a backslash**.
Suppose your values have dots, then the easiest way is to use `[regex]::Escape()` on each of those words before you combine them with the regex OR character (`|`) like this:

```
$a = 'option.1'
# this is the list of values you want to test inside the switch
$list = 'option.1', 'option.2'

# now create a regex string 'option\.1|option\.2' from that list
$regexCheck = ($list | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

switch -Regex ($a) {
    $regexCheck { <# Do the same thing... #> }
    default     { <# Do something else if the above does not apply #> }
}
```

**Special Characters in Regex**

| Char | Description | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \ | Backslash | Used to escape a special character |
| ^ | Caret | Beginning of a string |
| $ | Dollar sign | End of a string |
| . | Period or dot | Matches any single character |
| | | Vertical bar or pipe symbol | Matches previous OR next character/group |
| ? | Question mark | Match zero or one of the previous |
| * | Asterisk or star | Match zero, one or more of the previous |
| + | Plus sign | Match one or more of the previous |
| ( ) | Opening and closing parenthesis | Group characters |
| [ ] | Opening and closing square bracket | Matches a range of characters |
| { } | Opening and closing curly brace | Matches a specified number of occurrences of the previous |

Comment: @mklement0 Good point. I have added that to the answer.

Comment: I appreciate it, @Theo (you already had my +1).

Answer (score 0):

You are new in Powershell, then take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch

Working with match lists can be easy managed this way ...

```
# Switch argument and match lists:
$Local:a = "optionA"
$Local:SwitchCase_1_List = @("option1", "option2")
$Local:SwitchCase_2_List = @("optionA", "optionB")

# Run 
switch ($a){
    { $SwitchCase_1_List.Contains($a) } {
         Write-Host -Object "Do the something because of switch case 1 ..."
         break
    }
    { $SwitchCase_2_List.Contains($a) } {
         Write-Host -Object "Do the something because of switch case 2 ..."
         break
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest not showing the `$Local:` scope, as it is implied and rarely used in practice. While using the `.Contains()` .NET `IList` method works, not that it isn't fully equivalent to performing `-eq` comparisons on each element, because the latter is case-_insensitive_, as PowerShell generally is by default (the opposite of .NET APIs). Therefore the better choice is to use PowerShell's `-contains` _operator_ (or, with the operands reversed, the `-in` operator).

Comment: Finally, you should use `$_` - not `$a` - in the condition script blocks, which not only avoids repetition, but generally ensures only the item at hand is being referenced, given that `switch` can operate on _arrays_, and then evaluates its branches _for each element_.

Answer (score -4):

The left side of -eq can be a list:

```
switch ('option1','option2','option3') 
{
  {'option1','option2' -eq $_} {"$_ : Do the same thing..."}
  default {"$_ : Or do this..."}
}

option1 : Do the same thing...
option2 : Do the same thing...
option3 : Or do this...
```

Comment: It can, but that isn't suitable as a Boolean test. Try `if ((1, 2, 0) -eq 0) { 'never get here' }`

Comment: @mklement0 That's certainly an exception.

Comment: Try `if ((1, 2, '') -eq '') { 'never get here' }` or  `if ((1, 2, $null) -eq $null) { 'never get here' }` or `if ((1, 2, $false) -eq $false) { 'never get here' }`

Comment: The bottom line: don't use comparison-operator filtering to detect containment. Use the dedicated operators `-in` or `-contains`, which are also more efficient, because they don't (always) have to look at _all_ elements, and they don't have to construct a result array.

Comment: @mklement0 Searching for '' or $null or $false in a list seems unlikely.

Comment: (a) I don't think so and (b) the measure of a good solution is not  whether it works _more often than not_, but whether it works _robustly_. Showcasing the filtering behavior of the comparison operators is worthwhile in general, but it is the _wrong tool_ for containment tests.